# Formulation of entropy distance from equilibrium for fluctuations of the extensive parameters

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am looking for a valid definition/formulation of the distance from equilibrium entropy $\Delta S$, with the request that: $$0 \geq \Delta S \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
The fluctuations in the extensive parameters $E, N$ are considered such that: $(\Delta E) /E \sim (\Delta N) /N \sim 1/\sqrt{N}$. Let's write for simplicity that it is only energy that fluctuates, $E \pm \Delta E$. I attempt the following solution: $$$$
For an isolated system of non-interacting particles with total energy $2E$, divided into two compartments, we have:
$$
S_{total}(2E) = k\ln \sum_{x} \Omega(x)\Omega(2E-x) \hspace{1cm} (2)
$$
Considering $E, N$ to be large the total number of accessible states, $$ \sum_{x} \Omega(x)\Omega(2E-x)$$ is sharply peaked at $Ω(E-\Delta E)Ω(E + \Delta E)$. $$$$
Thus, for fluctuations:
$$S_{total}(2E) > 2S(E) \geq S(E-\Delta E) + S(E+\Delta E) \hspace{1cm} (3)$$

I further take the courage to define: $$\Delta S \equiv S(E-\Delta E) + S(E+\Delta E) - 2S(E) \hspace{1cm} (4) $$ I arrive to the request that: $$0 \geq \Delta S \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

There is a mature treatment of equilibrium fluctuations by Y. Mishin at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2015.09.015 $$$$
Then, in order for $\Delta S$ to be a general and valid definition, it must be such that: $$\Delta S = \hat{S} - \tilde{S} \hspace{1cm} (5)$$ with $\hat{S}$ and $\tilde{S}$  defined in equations $(61)$, $(62)$ of the article mentioned above.
By Taylor expanding $S(E \pm \Delta E)$ around its average value $S(E)$  truncated at quadratic terms, and then by substituting the result into $(4)$, only the quadratic terms survive (multiplied by two). Then $(4)$, applied to a system of total energy $E$ (and not $2E$) and more fluctuating extensive parameters $(X_i)$ does agree with the relation $(79)$. Requirement $(1)$ should also be compatible with the requirement for the "stability matrix" $($as defined by equation $(80))$ to be positive-definite. $$$$ Question: Is it compatible? $$$$ For fluctuations, microcanonical and canonical ensembles are considered equivalent. So I believe (and correct me if I am wrong) that $(2)$ is also numerically valid for the canonical ensemble, in the thermodynamic limit. $$$$

My main question is whether or not $(4)$ is a general and valid definition for the distance from the equilibrium entropy. Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Your requirement (1) seems weird: The $\Delta S$ are, by definition, deviations of the entropy from its average value (the cited paper, just before (21)). If all deviations are non-positive, then they have to be zero.

Comment: @kricheli per your suggestion, I clarified the terms "distance" and "fluctuations" although I still use $\Delta$ for both.

Comment: "The distance from the equilibrium entropy"? What does that mean to you? What do you want to use it for? Just reading those words would suggest something like the difference $S - S_{eq}$ between the entropy $S$ and the equilibrium entropy $S_{eq}$. Why you would want to define otherwise I currently do not see.